# My Laravel projects open in file structure on MacOS

Tags: php, laravel, apache, web, homebrew

I was using Windows before and I was developing Laravel projects on Windows. Now I will continue to develop on the Macbook. I'm new to using macOS. I installed Apache server and PHP with Brew. I also installed Composer. All working flawlessly. I also set the virtual host options correctly. But my Laravel projects still open in the file structure.

When I run the `composer install` command, I get the following error. Could it have something to do with it?

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/emre
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
```

Laravel Version: 8.83.25
PHP Version: 8.1.12

My Sample Laravel Project:
[image]

My httpd-vhosts.conf file:
[httpd-vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Am6w.png)

My hosts file:
[hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nvhD.png)

Comment: "_Laravel Version: 4.2.17_"? That version is over 10 years old, better upgrade

Comment: Looks like `/Users/emre` is _not_ your project folder. You probably didn't "_set the virtual host options correctly_"

Comment: What is your privileged reason to use this version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel Valet is your solution without the headache for development. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet

Comment: Laravel 4.2 will not work on PHP 8.1. (and should not be used anymore)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Laravel version is 8.83.25. Sorry, I'm a little sick so I made a mistake.

Comment: @OMiShah Laravel Valet solved my problem, thank you!